# mux.Vars not working

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm running on HTTPS (port 10443) and use subroutes:

```
mainRoute := mux.NewRouter()
mainRoute.StrictSlash(true)
mainRoute.Handle("/", http.RedirectHandler("/static/", 302))
mainRoute.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static", *fh))

// Bind API Routes
apiRoute := mainRoute.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()

apiProductRoute := apiRoute.PathPrefix("/products").Subrouter()
apiProductRoute.Handle("/", handler(listProducts)).Methods("GET")
```

And the functions:

```
func listProducts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, *handleHTTPError) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)

    productType, ok := vars["id"]
    log.Println(productType)
    log.Println(ok)
}
```

`ok` is `false` and I have no idea why. I'm doing a simple `?type=model` after my URL..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you enter a URL like `somedomain.com/products?type=model` you're specifying a query string, not a variable.

Query strings in Go are accessed via `r.URL.Query` - e.g.

```
vals := r.URL.Query() // Returns a url.Values, which is a map[string][]string
productTypes, ok := vals["type"] // Note type, not ID. ID wasn't specified anywhere.
var pt string
if ok {
    if len(productTypes) >= 1 {
        pt = productTypes[0] // The first `?type=model`
    }
}
```

As you can see, this can be a little clunky as it has to account for the map value being empty and for the possibility of a URL like `somedomain.com/products?type=model&this=that&here=there&type=cat` where a key can be specified more than once.

As [per the gorilla/mux docs](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) you can use route variables:

```
   // List all products, or the latest
   apiProductRoute.Handle("/", handler(listProducts)).Methods("GET")
   // List a specific product
   apiProductRoute.Handle("/{id}/", handler(showProduct)).Methods("GET")
```

This is where you would use `mux.Vars`:

```
vars := mux.Vars(request)
id := vars["id"]
```

Hope that helps clarify. I'd recommend the variables approach unless you specifically need to use query strings.

Comment: What about query parameters? @elithrar

Comment: @kamal "Query strings in Go are accessed via r.URL.Query"

Comment: There is a typo in the code it has to be `if len(productTypes) >= 1`

Comment: I expected `mux.Vars(r)` to return query parameters as well, but it does not seem to. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @LukePighetti `mux.Vars(r)` returns the route variables from mux. Query parameters are returned via `r.URL.Query`.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to solve this is to add query parameters in your route through `Queries`, like:

```
apiProductRoute.Handle("/", handler(listProducts)).
                Queries("type","{type}").Methods("GET")
```

You can get it using:

```
v := mux.Vars(r)
type := v["type"]
```

NOTE: This might not have been possible when the question was originally posted but I stumbled across this when I encountered a similar problem and the gorilla docs helped.